# make tree data structure from query in Arangodb

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have 2 collections:

- `root` - vertices
- `root_edges` - edges

Each `root_edge` connects 2 `root` documents. I want to be able to make a query so that it will return nested data structure representing the data tree.

I want something like this:

```
A: {
    id: <int>,
    name: <string>
    B: {
        id: <int>,
        name: <string>,
        C: {
            id: <int>,
            name: <string>
        },
        D: {
            id: <int>,
            name: <string>
        }
    }
    E: {
        id: <int>,
        name: <string>,
        F: {
            id: <int>,
            name: <string>
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how many levels can be there, so I need a flexible solution.
What I have now produces a flat list of all edges and/or vertices.

Comment: You said: “What I have now produces a flat list of all edges and/or vertices”, what query do you mean? And if I understood you correctly, your graph is actually a tree. I mean all of your nodes are connected in a way that they are all formally a tree nodes. Am I right?

Comment: If you have a lot of data, you would return one gigantic document - that doesn't sound good to me; Traverse the graph and use a cursor to handle the data, and build the structure on the client side